# fundamentals mock test SCJP

Tags: java

**Given the code below. This code is run by "java Test 1 2 3 4". What is the result?**

```
public class Test { 

public static void main(String args[]) {

for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {

         System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

A) Compilation fails.

B) An exception is thrown at runtime.

C) 1 2 3

D) 1 2

E) 2 3

This is from SCJP and answer given is "1 2 3". But it's supposed to be "1 2" as args.length = 3, so the loop will execute 2 times giving output as "1 2". Correct me if I am wrong.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you think `args.length` is 3? How many arguments you pass when run your program?

Comment: `java Test 1 2 3 4` says there are 4 args. So `args.length` is 4. And the loop runs 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

`args.length` is `4`, `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`, and `"4"`.  Because this loop starts out with `1`, the first argument, `1`, is effectively skipped, and the loop runs 3 times, not 2 times, that is, once each for the last 3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

`args.length` is actually 4. How can it be 3?

Answer (score 0):

Yes args length is 4. For arrays the index starts with 0. You might have got confused with that. When you count a array length it starts with 1 not 0.

Answer (score 0):

args.length = 4 in this case. Length of an array is the number of elements within it - 4 in this case. Since the counter starts at 1 (and should stop at 3), it will print 1, 2, 3